# Is Spring.NET project dead?

Tags: .net, spring, spring.net

We are considering using Sprint.NET as AOP framework along with other solutions. Spring.NET is a known framework, at least by name like in my case.

I try to find the informations about latest release and support but I can't find anything after 2012 to my surprise.

Is the project dead ?

Where is the up-to-date website/forum/support?

Google did not really helped me on that point :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Despite [having a dead website](http://www.springframework.net/), nor being listed at [spring.io](https://spring.io/projects), there is still (in 2015 at least) development activity at [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPRNET/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) and [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/commits/main).

---

It appears development continues in [spring-net-futures](https://github.com/spring-net-futures/spring-net/commits/feature/netstandard-2.0), but there's only one person. As far as production usage goes I'd say it's dead now, but it might come back at some point.

---

Last commit there was Nov 2017. It's certainly dead now.

---

Activity started again in the original repo, but only ten commits in the last year (as of June 2020).

Comment: Another commit last week!

Answer (score 8):

I found this question after doing a Google search for "spring.net", following the top link to [springframework.net](https://springframework.net), and seeing the last news update is dated December 11th, 2012.

It looks like the project was resuscitated in September of 2018. The [GitHub home page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net) now shows version 3.0.0 (Prerelease) supporting .Net 4.5.2 and .Net Standard 2.0.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that version on nuget.org at this point, so from the point of view of a consuming developer it remains *effectively* dead.