# What are the attributes needed to read a Tibco EMS message queue from C#

Tags: c#, tibco-ems

I'm getting the following exception thrown
when executing the AfterPropertiesSet():

*Not allowed to create destination*

**From Java guys I was given these:**

> pt-jndi-url: tibjmsnaming://tibjndi-pt.mycompany.com:12420

> pt-project1-username: ticketsappsgreeks-ext

> pt-project1-password: tickets41040

> queue name: ALS.QA.tickets.TEST.QUEUE_CONNECTION

> pt-project1-jndi-queue-connection-factory-name: ALS.PT.tickets.greeks.QCF.MS

**I translated these into the following in the C# calls:**

> Uri : tibjndi-pt.mycompany.com:12420

> User : ticketsappsgreeks-ext

> Pwd : tickets41040

> TargetHostName : tibjndi-pt.mycompany.com

> Destination : ALS.QA.tickets.TEST.QUEUE_CONNECTION

**Environment:**

- Windows 10 Using
- VS 2017
- TIBCO.EMS.DLL  1.0.851.4
- Spring.Messaging.Ems 2.0.1

C# Code:

```
private readonly SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
                
                connectionFactory = new Spring.Messaging.Ems.Common.EmsConnectionFactory(Uri);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(User))
                {
                    connectionFactory.UserName = User;
                    Logger.Info($"User : {User}");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Pwd))
                {
                    connectionFactory.UserPassword = Pwd;
                    Logger.Info($"Pwd : {Pwd}");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetHostName))
                {
                    connectionFactory.TargetHostName = TargetHostName;
                    Logger.Info($"TargetHostName : {TargetHostName}");
                }
                
                connectionFactory.ClientID = "testClient1";
                
                try
                {
                    Logger.Debug($"Destination - {DestinationName}");

                    this.listenerContainer.ConnectionFactory = connectionFactory;
                    this.listenerContainer.DestinationName = DestinationName;
                    this.listenerContainer.ConcurrentConsumers = 1;
                    this.listenerContainer.PubSubDomain = false;
                    this.listenerContainer.MessageListener = new MessageListener(Logger);
                    this.listenerContainer.ExceptionListener = new ExceptionListener(Logger);
                    this.listenerContainer.MaxRecoveryTime = new TimeSpan(MaxRecoveryTimeInDays, 0, 0, 0);
                    this.listenerContainer.RecoveryInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10, 0); // set to 10 Minutes  
                    this.listenerContainer.AcceptMessagesWhileStopping = false;
                    this.listenerContainer.SessionAcknowledgeMode = AckMode;
                    this.listenerContainer.AfterPropertiesSet();
                    if (this.listenerContainer.IsRunning)
                    {
                        Logger.Debug("Listener IsRunning.");
                    }

                }
                catch (EMSException e)
                {
                    Logger.Error($"EMSException : {e.Message}");

                    if (e.LinkedException != null)
                    {
                        Logger.Error($"EMSException Linked Exception error msg : {e.LinkedException.Message}");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you found your way here then you probably wasted the same amount of time that I did researching how to read a Tibco EMS queue.

Do not use the SpringFamework for .Net since it's dead.
Instead go back and download the Tibco community edition and start with the samples provided by the vendor.

Found this:
[Is Spring.NET project dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770202/is-spring-net-project-dead/59648443#59648443)